# Layered scatterplot with spline for means

Tags: r, grouping, scatter-plot, spline

I'm trying to plot animal behaviour over a series of days with individual animals colour coded in a scatter plot and a smooth line showing the mean over the dots. The closest I've come is using lattice like this, where "Standing" is the specific behaviour I'm looking at:

```
xyplot(data=data2, 
       Standing ~ Day, 
       type = c("p", "spline"))
```

This looks nice but doesn't differentiate the dots. If I try using group = Sheep it also divides the lines. I don't know how to group one but not the other.

I also tried using ggplot2, but geo_smooth() doesn't seem to give me the kind of line I want and the following code doesn't work.

```
means <- tapply(data3$Standing, data3$Day, mean)
ggplot(data3, aes(x = Day, y = Standing)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Sheep)) +   
  geom_line(data = data.frame(spline(means)))
```

My dataset looks like this:

```
   Sheep Day Block Standing Lying Eating Ruminating Moving Fence Pawing Social Scratching
1      2  -4     0       49    12     36         16      0     0      1      0          0
12     4  -4     0       46    13     32         15      0     2      0      0          0
23     5  -4     0       48    13     32         22      0     0      0      0          0
34     6  -4     0       48    12     36         17      0     0      0      0          0
45     2  -3     0       45    19     39         20      2     0      1      0          0
56     4  -3     0       30    27     35         24      6     4      0      0          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the `ggplot` check out `stat_smooth`, I think that is what you're after.

You don't need to calculate `means` beforehand since `stat_smooth` should do that for you. If you want to use splines, there is a [spline example here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_smooth.html).

In this example it isn't very helpful, but based on your dataset I can produce the following graphs:

```
ggplot(data2, aes(x=Day, y=Standing, color=Sheep)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method=lm)
```

[image]

```
library(splines)
ggplot(data2, aes(x=Day, y=Standing, color=Sheep)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method=lm, formula=y~ns(x,3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding correctly that you want to show values for individual animals as points only, and you want the line to summarize the trend across all of the animals?

If so, then you need to break the plotting into two steps: one to generate the scatter plot with coloring by group, and then another to compute the daily means and add a line connecting them to the original scatter plot.

For the first step, you can get colors by group (sheep) using `plot()` from base R if you specify the grouping variable as a factor in the call to color. So:

```
 with(data2, plot(Standing ~ Day, type = "p", pch=20, col=as.factor(Sheep)))
```

To add a line connecting the means across groups by day, use `tapply()` to calculate the means of Standing by Day, `spline()` or `lowess()` to connect the dots, and `lines()` to add that to the existing plot created in the first step. Here's a version using `lowess()`:

```
 with(data2, lines(lowess(tapply(Standing, Day, mean)), lwd=2))
```

I used this line to generate play data to confirm that this worked:

```
data2 <- data.frame(Sheep = c(rep(1,7), rep(2,7), rep(3,7), rep(4,7)),
  Standing = rnorm(n = 4 * 7, mean = 45, sd = 5),
  Day = rep(seq(7),4))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. You got what I meant, but I can't seem to make your code work. The scatter plot will show but the line isn't added on top. I get an error message saying "plot.new has not been called yet". I've never used the with() function before though so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. That problem seems to be specific to `xyplot()`, and I don't know that function or 'lattice' well enough to know how to solve it. If you just do the `plot()` version, though, it should work fine. So, `with(data2, plot(Standing ~ Day, type = "p", col = as.factor(Sheep)))` followed by `with(data2, lines(spline(tapply(Standing, Day, mean))))`. I'm also seeing that my suggestion for `loess()` doesn't work as intended, so I will edit my original answer to leave only the version that works.

Comment: That does kind of work but for some reason the line starts at 0 rather than at -4 while the dots are correctly places. So they don't correspond. It's the same if I try to plot the means by themselves, even if the values that are generated definitely start with a mean for -4. I keep thinking there must be a way of doing this in ggplot2 that I haven't figured out.

Comment: In base R, you can customize the axes, including labels, by specifying `axes = FALSE` in the original call to `plot()` and then using `axis()` like you did '`lines()` here to add new versions with the desired labels and such. So if you want x-axis labels that start at -4, for example, you would do something like `axis(1, at=seq(7), labels=seq(-4,2,1))`.